# java server (simple example) displaying only the first string sent

Tags: sockets, client-server, java-server

Hi i want to test if my client app is working by testing it on a very simple java server. My client will send a string almost every second. My idea is that the server will display the string in the eclipse console once it receives the string. But the problem is that the simple java server only prints out the first string. Below is the simple java server i got from the [site](http://pguides.net/java/tcp-client-server-chat)

```
  package serverjava;

/* ChatServer.java */
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class serverjava {
    private static int port = 1234; /* port the server listens on */

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port); /* start listening on the port */
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /* obtain an input stream to the client */
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    client.getInputStream()));

        String msg;
        /* loop reading lines from the client and display them */
        while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Client says: " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Is the java server capable of displaying only an instance of a string per launch? If yes, how can I make it to print or show in the console all the strings that are being sent every second?

Comment: If your client closes the connection each time, this is expected.

Comment: yes the client does closes almost every second and will try to connect and send almost every second. What should i do with my simple java server tester?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you read the buffer only one time. The server waits for client lines and when it reads them, then it finish the execution because 'msg' is null. You must have a process that reads every second or minute, or hour... That means using **THREADS**.

- If you want to see **more examples**, go here:
  http://www.isr.umd.edu/~austin/ence489c.d/threads.html.
- And here you have some **information**:
  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-1996/jw-04-threads.html

***Be careful!*** Don't use a while(true) structure of something like that, because the machine will be overloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the help and comments. I used the other code in the link http://pguides.net/java/tcp-client-server-chat
and it worked now.